# How to manually set a CMake path variable to NOTFOUND?

Tags: cmake, unset, file-not-found

I'm hardcoding a library path before hand and want to set the path to NOTFOUND manually if the file doesn't exist.

```
set(MY_LIB "path that doesn't exist")
if(NOT EXISTS "${MY_LIB}")
 message("not found")
 // set it back to NOTFOUND ??
endif()
if (MY_LIB)
 // set flags
endif()
```

Comment: `set(MY_LIB "NOTFOUND")`?

Comment: Would that serve as a conditional later on ?

Comment: I do not understand. "Serve" how? How exactly? In which "conditional"? Is a "conditional" in your question an `if` statement?

Comment: Edited the question. conditional means the second if statement in the code.

Comment: Read [if cmake manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html) and you'll find the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to manually set a CMake path variable to NOTFOUND?

Just set it to the string:

```
set(MY_LIB "NOTFOUND")
```